# Area of Plot in shiny using ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Hi I am using the below code, I am using the plot at the bottom to filter the plot at the top

Sample Data : 
headings :- ComplaintID;    Date Complaint Received;    Is Regulatory Complaint?;   Days Complaint is Open; Text Days Complaint is Open. 
Values for each heading:-
973;    16-Nov; No; 0;  Complaints Open for 0 Days,
972;    16-Nov; No; 0;  Complaints Open for 0 Days,
971;    16-Nov; No; 0;  Complaints Open for 0 Days.

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(

   # Application title
   headerPanel("Filter by month"),

   sidebarPanel(
         selectizeInput("YrMon",
                     "Filter by Month-Year:" ,
                     choices = unique(CCMS3$ccmsdate), "11-16", multiple = TRUE
                     ),


    radioButtons("Regcmp", "Regulatory Complaint :", choices = unique(CCMS3$Is.Regulatory.Complaint.),selected = 'No'),

         sliderInput(inputId="dayscmp", label="Days Complaint Open :", step=10,min = min(CCMS3$Days.Complaint.is.Open),max=max(CCMS3$Days.Complaint.is.Open),value = c(0,150))

   ),       
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("histPlt"),
         plotOutput("histplt2", click = clickOpts(id="flt",clip = FALSE), dblclick = "sm"),       
         textOutput("asd")
         )
   )

server <- function(input, output) {


  library(dplyr)



  output$histPlt <- renderPlot({ 

  if(!is.even(length(input$flt)) & !is.null(input$flt))  {

  nwflt2 <- factor(CCMS$Text.Days.Complaint.is.Open)

  nwflt1 <- unique(nwflt2)

  nwflt <- nwflt1[round(input$flt$x)]

  ddd <- ({filter(CCMS3, Text.Days.Complaint.is.Open %in% nwflt & ccmsdate %in% input$YrMon & Is.Regulatory.Complaint. %in% input$Regcmp & Days.Complaint.is.Open %in% (input$dayscmp[1] : input$dayscmp[2]))})


  require(ggplot2)
  library(ggplot2)

  g <- ggplot(ddd, aes_string(x='ccmsdate'))

  plr <- g+geom_bar()+ylab("")+ggtitle("Number Of Complaints By Date")+xlab('Date(Year-Month)')+scale_x_discrete(labels= addline_format(c(unique(ddd$ccmsdate))),limits=c(unique(ddd$ccmsdate)))

  gg <- plr+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10,colour="Blue",hjust=0.5,vjust=1),axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),panel.background=element_rect(fill="White",colour="Black"),panel.grid=element_blank())

  gg

   } else  

     { ddd <- ({filter(CCMS3, ccmsdate %in% input$YrMon & Is.Regulatory.Complaint. %in% input$Regcmp & Days.Complaint.is.Open %in% (input$dayscmp[1] : input$dayscmp[2]))})


   require(ggplot2)
   library(ggplot2)

   g <- ggplot(ddd, aes_string(x='ccmsdate'))

   plr <- g+geom_bar()+ylab("")+ggtitle("Number Of Complaints By Date")+xlab('Date(Year-Month)')+scale_x_discrete(labels= addline_format(c(unique(ddd$ccmsdate))),limits=c(unique(ddd$ccmsdate)))

   gg <- plr+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10,colour="Blue",hjust=0.5,vjust=1),axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),panel.background=element_rect(fill="White",colour="Black"),panel.grid=element_blank())

   gg     }})

output$histplt2 <- renderPlot({ 

  ddd <- ({filter(CCMS3, ccmsdate %in% input$YrMon & Is.Regulatory.Complaint.%in% input$Regcmp & Days.Complaint.is.Open %in% (input$dayscmp[1] : input$dayscmp[2]))})

  g2 <- ggplot(ddd, aes_string(x='Text.Days.Complaint.is.Open'))

  plr2 <- g2+geom_bar()+ylab("")+ggtitle("Number Of Complaints By Complaints Open")+xlab('Date(Year-Month)')+scale_x_discrete(labels= addline_format(c(unique(ddd$Text.Days.Complaint.is.Open))),limits=c(unique(ddd$Text.Days.Complaint.is.Open)))

  gg2 <- plr2+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10,colour="Blue",hjust=0.5,vjust=1),axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),panel.background=element_rect(fill="White",colour="Black"),panel.grid=element_blank())

  gg2

  })
}
```

Now I am not able to reset the graph at the top again until I change the values in the filter. I want to create something where if the user clicks on the graph within the plotted area then it should be filtered else if it is outside the plotted area it should not be filtered and the graph at the top should also be unfiltered.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share sample data for CCMS?

Comment: @sandipan i have added the sample data.